# Syntax error from SQL workbench

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id = ? AND branch_id = ?
```

I am not sure why i am getting syntax error for this sql statement.

Comment: `?` is placeholder for parameter value. Did you pass any value instead `?`

Comment: Yes, ? is a placeholder for parameter value

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your database has a table `product` with the columns `product_id` and `branch_id`. Did you provide a value for the `?` placeholders?

Like so; for example:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id = 1 AND branch_id = 200
```